# Is there a RESTful way to determine whether a POST will succeed?

Tags: validation, rest, transactions, rollback

Is there a RESTful way to determine whether a POST (or any other non-idempotent verb) will succeed?  This would seem to be useful in cases where you essentially need to do multiple idempotent requests against different services, any of which might fail.  It would be nice if these requests could be done in a "transaction" (i.e. with support for rollback), but since this is impossible, an alternative is to check whether each of the requests will succeed before actually performing them.

For example suppose I'm building an ecommerce system that allows people to buy t-shirts with custom text printed on them, and this system requires integrating with two different services: a t-shirt printing service, and a payment service.  Each of these has a RESTful API, and either might fail.  (e.g. the printing company might refuse to print certain words on a t-shirt, say, and the bank might complain if the credit card has expired.)  Is there any way to speculatively perform these two requests, so my system will only proceed with them if both requests appear valid?

If not, can this problem be solved in a different way?  Creating a resource via a `POST` with `status = pending`, and changing this to `status = complete` if all requests succeed?  (`DELETE` is more tricky...)

Comment: Another approach: a `POST` with `persist = false` or `ephemeral = true`.  (Feels a bit hacky, but doesn't require a subsequent `status` change--when you really want the `POST` to happen, issue it again.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP defines the 202 status code for exactly your scenario:

> 202 Accepted
>
> The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place. There is no facility for re-sending a status code from an asynchronous operation such as this.
>
> The 202 response is intentionally non-committal. Its purpose is to allow a server to accept a request for some other process (perhaps a batch-oriented process that is only run once per day) without requiring that the user agent's connection to the server persist until the process is completed. The entity returned with this response SHOULD include an indication of the request's current status and either a pointer to a status monitor or some estimate of when the user can expect the request to be fulfilled.

Source: [HTTP 1.1 Status Code Definition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

This is similar to 201 Created, except that you are indicating that the request has not been completed and the entity has not yet been created. Your response would contain a URL to the resource representing the "order request", so clients can check the status of the order through this URL.

---

To answer your question more directly: There is no way to "test" whether a request will succeed before you make it, because **you're asking for clairvoyance.**

It's not possible to foresee the range of technical problems that could occur when you attempt to make a request in the future. The network may be unavailable, the server may not be able to access its database or external systems it depends on for functioning, there may be a power-cut and the server is offline, a stray neutrino could wander into your memory and bump a 0 to a 1 causing a catastrophic kernel fault.

In order to consume a remote service you need to account for possible failures of any request in isolation of any other processes.

For your specific problem, if the services have no transactional safety, you can't bake any in there and you have to deal with this in a more real-world way. A few options off the top of my head:

1. Get the T-Shirt company to give you a "test" mechanism, so you can see whether they'll process any given order without actually placing it. It could be that placing an order with them is a two-phase operation, where you construct the order in the first phase (at which time they validate its creation) and then you subsequently ask the order to be processed (after you have taken payment successfully).
2. Take the credit-card payment first and move your order into a "paid" state. Then attempt to fulfil the order with the T-Shirt service as an asynchronous process. If fulfilment fails and you can identify that the customer tried to get something printed the company is not prepared to produce, you will have to contact them to change their order or produce a refund.

Most organizations will adopt the second approach, due to its technical simplicity and reduced risk to the business. It also has the benefit of being able to cope with the T-Shirt service not being available; the asynchronous process simply waits until the service is available and completes the order at that time.

Comment: Uh, sorry, I meant "non-idempotent" (question updated, although thinking about it again now, the question also applies to `PUT`, which is idempotent...).  Anyway, I'm pretty sure a 202 doesn't suit my purposes--it's issued by the *server*, irrespective of what the client wants.  (Perhaps the customer can't purchase the t-shirt at all, because they don't have a valid credit card.)

Comment: Understood. Removed my words on idempotency.

Comment: @mjs: then you have to create another level of indirection and create (either in the client or in another service) a "transaction coordinator" that both checks when the requests are ready, and also fails if some of the services called refuse to continue.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly. That can be done as you suggest in your last sentence. The idea would be to decopule resource creation (that will always work unless network failures) that represents an "ongoing request" of the "order acceptation", that can be later decided. As POST returns a "Location" header, you can then retrieve in any moment the "status" of your request.

At some point it may become either accepted or rejected. This may be intantaneous or it may take some time, so you have to design your service with these restrictions (i.e. allowing the client to check if his/her order is accepted, or running some kind of hourly/daily service that collect accepted requests).